# Register Java Script only if proper event occured

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I want to fire script on page only when user triggers proper event. In my case user by button click adds new record to database. I'am able to obtain dynamically created control reference with new record in code behind , I just don't know how from code behind pass it this single time to JavaScript that will fire after page loads.
My script will look like this :

```
function(id) {
   document.getElementByID(id).focus()
}
```

I'am using .net framework **1.1** 
 Do you have idea how I can accomplish this task ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider

1. What is the *EventTarget*? If you want to wait until the whole page has finished loading, then `window` is the *EventTarget* you're looking for because it's the top-most *DOM* related *Object* you can reference.
2. Which event do you want to listen for? Again, if you want to detect page loading, you're listening for *load*, which is the name of the event.

So, using [`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // code to execute when this handler is invoked
});
```

---

**Edit:** I'm not sure your environment will have `window`, if it doesn't then you'll probably want the highest *Node* you can access in your *DOM* structure.

Comment: I forgot to ad that I'am working on framework **1.1**

Comment: @user3455363 Maybe [**this page**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5bccb2fc-facf-4f90-a721-55668cfcde1c/fyi-fixing-javascript-events-with-net-framework-11-and-sp1?forum=winformssetup) will help. Please note that **since the beginning of April 2014, _Windows XP_ has now reached end of life**, the oldest _.NET Framework_ that didn't die with it is **version 3.0**